# Drawing graphs with purely HTML5

Tags: css, html, html5-canvas

Can any one point me to any resources for making graphs in **HTML5**? Most of resources I have seen through Google use animated graphs, I just want a simple static graph in HTML5. One more thing, I am really very weak in graphs, so a simple, easy to understand solution would be very helpful. I will be using this XML file to display data in graphical format. 
[US Canada Mortality](http://www-acad.sheridanc.on.ca/~joe/SYST35288/2012/assignments/uscanadamortality.xml)

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Is this for homework? If so, add the `homework` tag.

Comment: I assume that by HTML5 graph, you mean that you want to use the `<canvas>` element, right? If so, you should really just be looking for tutorials on drawing to the canvas if you want to do it yourself. Or if you want a whole package solution, maybe: http://www.humblesoftware.com/flotr2/

Comment: Yes, I want to use <canvas> element.I would try using that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the new `canvas` tag.  It allows you to draw shapes including rectangles and circles using javascript.  [Canvas Tutorials](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/)

If you're looking for just a standard bar chart, though, you can use the `div` tag with a specified width, height, and background color.  This method avoids the use of javascript.

Comment: The SVG element would also be suitable as a drawing environment that doesn't require Javascript. For a dynamic solution, canvas would work well with some AJAX to load the XML.

Comment: Canvas with XML? is it possible?

Comment: Whether this is “purely HTML5” depends on your definition of “HTML5”. The W3C HTML5 draft just defines the `canvas` element and refers to the Canvas API. All the drawing must be done in JavaScript, using that API, which is defined outside the draft.